# Testing rig mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, testing

I have searched the internet for a while now. And the worst thing is I have seen a testing rig before, but can't find it anymore.

Does anyone know a testing rig for mobile devices? Or should I build something myself. It is intended for testing an application on different devices (eg. iPad, Galaxy tab 10, iPhone, etc.)

Or when I had my eyes shut please pass me a link to the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're asking about [Samsung's Developer Test Lab](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/). It allows you to spin up a bunch of virtual Samsung Android devices and test stuff on it.

I haven't used it personally, so YMMV, and it's also limited to Samsung/Android -- no iOS.

Comment: The thing I'm searching for is a physical board on which you can place several mobile devices. So you'll be testing with the actual smart phone.

Answer (score 0):

For those that wondered as well. The article I found some time ago, and couldn't find anymore but did find yesterday, is this http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/10/22/a-guide-to-mobile-app-testing/.

Here you can set up different mobile devices and make a test lab. Thanks for the response!